# Unexpected Token u

Tags: json, angularjs

I am getting error as 'Unexpected Token u' whenever the session variable is not having the value. My code is..

```
var myApp = angular.module('MyApp ', ['ngStorage']);

myApp .controller('MyApp Ctrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$sessionStorage',
    function ($scope, $http, $sessionStorage,) {

    $scope.selectedDoctor = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.DocOID);

}]);
```

Eventhough i have tried like as

```
$scope.selectedDoctor = JSON.parse($sessionStorage.DocOID);
```

Advice me.....

Comment: how did you add data in sessionStorage ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Cause** : When the session storage had no variable named `DocOID` it returns `undefined` as output. Hence the error `Unexpected Token "u"`

Please check if the value exists before accessing it to circumvent this error. You could use either

```
 if ($sessionStorage.DocOID  !== undefined) { 
    //do stuff 
  }
```

or

```
if ($sessionStorage.hasOwnProperty('DocOID')) { 
    //do stuff 
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

did u tried it with if ($sessionStorage.hasOwnProperty('DocOID'))
and then

`Json.parse($sessionStorage.DocOID)`